# Why is Christianity so despised in the World?

Tags: exegesis

Since its inception, Christianity has been ill received through out the world. This is true not only of people, but of Governments as well.

It is easy to understand why the Sanhedrin was so opposed to Jesus, since he was messing up their little playhouse, but since the main themes of his teachings were peace and harmony, why are these ideas so abhorrent?

> John 13:34  KJV A new commandment I give unto you, That ye love one another; as I have loved you, that ye also love one another.
>
> Matthew 22:21  KJV  They say unto him, Caesar's. Then saith he unto them, Render therefore unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's; and unto God the things that are God's
>
> Matthew 5:7  KJV  Blessed are the merciful: for they shall obtain mercy.
>
> Mat 5:44  But I say unto you, Love your enemies, bless them that curse you, do good to them that hate you, and pray for them which despitefully use you, and persecute you;

Are these precepts so opposed to the power struggles and quest for riches that most societies believe they must be eradicated?

What are the arguments used that vilify Christianity?

Comment: Er, Christianity is the dominant religion in much of the world, and has often been adopted as an official state religion. It has that status in many many countries (including, de facto, the USA). In other words, you're talking utter nonsense.

Comment: maybe if you add the Philosophy tag you wont get so much hate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the source of hatred often perceived by Christians in western society?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/724/what-is-the-source-of-hatred-often-perceived-by-christians-in-western-society)

Comment: Are you asking for a theological explanation? If so, according to whom?  Or are you asking for a sociological explanation? If so, this question is off-topic.

Comment: This is prime case of asking for opinions.

Comment: @Flimzy I am looking for neither, Normally when people dislike something they use some sort of reasoning. Even though I do not see any reason why Christianity should be objectionable, apparently some Governments and some people do find something about it offensive. I simply would like to understand that reasoning. In order to outlaw it some arguments had to be put forth, what are those arguments? Can you or anyone else direct me to where that information might be found.

Comment: @DJClayworth Quite to the contrary I am asking for the reasoning used to object to Christianity rather than anyone's opinion, for which I could care less. I want the points of argument used.

Comment: @CecilBeckum: So you're seeking opinions... also off-topic.

Comment: @ Flimsy no I am looking for what arguments are used to vilify Christianity.

Comment: **Mod notice:** Please _stop_ using comments to debate issues, that is not what the function is here for. You may use them to request clarification or suggest improvements to posts but not for debating theology/policits/history/whatever else. In other words comments should be focused _on the post_ not on the issues the post focuses on.

Answer (score 6):

Jesus said,

> If the world hates you, you know that it hated Me before it hated you.
>   19 If you were of the world, the world would love its own. Yet because
>   you are not of the world, but I chose you out of the world, therefore
>   the world hates you. 20 Remember the word that I said to you, ‘A
>   servant is not greater than his master.’ If they persecuted Me, they
>   will also persecute you. If they kept My word, they will keep yours
>   also. 21 But all these things they will do to you for My name’s sake,
>   because they do not know Him who sent Me.
>
> John 15:18-21

Satan has power in this world and will persecute the followers of Jesus until he is destroyed. Sometimes the hatred is irrational, sometimes it is excused by the actions of so-called Christians. Nevertheless the real reason is because Jesus is hated by Satan. He cannot touch Jesus so he goes after those who are dear to Him. Sometimes Jesus allows it for a purpose, to build our character, but sometimes he does not allow it.

It is not the Christian principles that people hate. Most of the time they do not know what Christians believe. It is the hatred put in their hearts by the enemy himself.

The truth is, if you were in the path of destruction, would Satan
 care? No, he would leave you just as you are. However if you are in
 the path of righteousness, and bringing other souls from perdition
 into salvation, Satan would hate you. So he would do everything in his
 power to kill you, hurt you, discourage you, or make you doubt.
 EVERYONE in the Bible that followed God was persecuted, hurt, and
 sometimes killed. Most of the prophets were murdered. Jesus Himself
 was murdered, hurt, persecuted, and called demon-possessed. If you
 follow Christ this is what you might face one day.

Comment: +1. Your one of the comment(tenth in the series) under the question has a good point which can also be included in this answer.

Comment: @jayyeshu Thank you brother. I have added the comment to the answer.

Comment: It was your view, which I found very pertinent. So accordingly, I have done a minor edit.

Comment: All of what you say is true and it is no mystery why Satan hates Christians, yet that does not answer the question of why do rational people see the teaching of Christianity and Jesus abhorrent.

Comment: @CecilBeckum I aimed to answer that in the 2nd sentence. Sometimes the answer is irrational, but sometimes it is based on the behavior of some nominal Christians that don't act how a Christian should. An example would be someone from Westboro Baptist Church, who call themselves Christians, but do not love the sinner. Love does not condemn, but it uplifts. Because of the actions of people such as these, people who do not know how a true Christian must be, tend to alienate themselves completely from Christians and their beliefs. Yet, behind this is always Satan casting doubt on Christianity.

Comment: I think Jesus answered that Matthew 7:22  Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied in thy name? and in thy name have cast out devils? and in thy name done many wonderful works? 
Matthew 7:23  And then will I profess unto them, I never knew you: depart from me, ye that work iniquity.

Comment: @CecilBeckum you are correct. That will be one bittersweet day. Bitter in that many will be lost, sweet in that it will be the day when sin will be no more.

Answer (score -5):

When I think of Jesus vs Sanhedrin. I'm thinking more about the struggle between Protestantism vs The Catholic Church, the [One true church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_true_church). Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism):

> Protestantism encompasses forms of Christian faith and practice that
>   originated with doctrines and religious, political, and
>   ecclesiological impulses of the Protestant Reformation against what
>   they considered the errors of the Catholic Church.

Why has Christianity has been ill received? Well Christian persecution is certain to happen. 2 Timothy 3:12 NET.

> Now in fact all who want to live godly lives in Christ Jesus will be
>   persecuted.

But about the power struggles and quest for riches. Usually that is between non-Christians. Christians have the [Great Commission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Commission) and they only need the Power of God to make that happen. Not the power of money.

Working among children all the time I find that when I question a kid that does a bad deed like bulling. They dont remember the details. They forget. They forget the rules. But what they dont know is that good kids are watching and they do remember the details and make a complain. I make a report and notify the parents.

Maybe that is why bad men feel ill about good men. Because they tattletale. Kinda like Able vs Cain.

Comment: I have to down vote your answer since it supports the idea that one church is Christian, but others are not. The truth is that the Roman Catholic church is far different than the Church established by the Apostles in Jerusalem, and was the first schism when it separated from the Jerusalem Church. The truth is in John 3:16.

Comment: Reread wiki and see what the word 'Catholic' literally means

Comment: Let's agree to disagree :)

Comment: -1 This answer is opinion, and doesn't represent any official doctrine.

Comment: With Pope "Who am I to judge?" Francis, you're still brazen enough to pretend the RCC is the one true church?  Some people never learn.